# Set autofocus for input on every render of parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with input with Style applied called StyledInput which is in NumericInputComponent which is being used in a PriceComponent. This is part of a line. Whenever I switch between the lines, I want to focus on this input. The autofocus works only for the first render and hence when I switch, it does not autofocus again. How do I force focus for every switch.

I tried forcing re render of Price Component but that did not help with the focus.

In Numeric Input

```
const StyledInput = styled('input')`
    transition: all 150ms;
    &:hover {
        border: 1px solid ${Colors.brands['04']};
    }    
`;


   <StyledInput
                type='tel'
                autoComplete='off'
                autoFocus={this.props.autoFocus}
                min={this.props.min}
                max={this.props.max}
                step={this.props.step}
                value={this.props.value}
                onFocus={this.props.onFocus}
                disabled={this.props.disabled}
                onClick={this.stopPropagation}
                required={this.props.required}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                className={this.props.className}
                onBlur={this.props.onBlur}
                ref={input => input && input.focus()}
            />
```

Inside PriceComponenet

```
const StyledNumericInput = styled(NumericInput)`
    padding: 0;          // remove mi-form-control padding
    text-align: center;
    &:required:focus {
        background-image: none;
    }
`;

<StyledNumericInput
                    autoFocus={this.shouldAutoFocus(this.props)}
                    className='mi-class'
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    min={this.props.line ? -99.9 : 0.0}
                    id={'priceEdit' + this.props.index}
                    max={99.9}
                    step={0.1}
                    onFocus={Utilities.selectAllText}
                    required
                />

Say I have 3 lines, everytime I swtich between lines (which will have name, qty and price), it should always focus on price, even when the name and qty does not change.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "every time I switch between lines"?

Comment: It means, I have a split view with a rows on the left. On clicking each row, it displays details on the left in the same format.